# FireDac error 314 - but DLLs are in program directory

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, windows-10, firedac

I am getting when trying to access a MySql database :

> [FireDac][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libmysql.dll
>   or libmysqlld.dll]

This did not previously happen with this (unchanged) code, however, I have upgraded to Windows 10 and had to reinstall Delphi XE8, so it is obviously a system configuration matter.

In order to try to solve the problem, I copied both of those files into c:\windows\sysytem32.

When that did not seem to work, I copied them into \win32\debug, which is where the generated .EXE resides.

I imagine that I am doing something rather stupid, but can't see what.

Comment: Please stop copying files to system32.  And FWIW, that's the 64 bit system directory so your 32 bit process can't see it. And please also don't copy them to syswow64, the 32 bit system directory, because that's also not yours to modify.

Comment: @Ken, thanks, that did the trick. Could you please post it as an answer, so that I Can accept it & make things clear for anyone who reads this question in future?

Comment: Feel free to write you own answer. If that answer suggests using system directory, then I'll gladly down vote!

Comment: @David, you have been virulently anti-system directory throughout your post. Could you please enlighten me as to why?  Copying to the app directory is burdensome, if you code a lot of apps, so it is more natural to place the DLLs in a directory on the search path. Why not a system directory, since that used to be the preferred way (AFAIK)? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It has never been the correct way. The system directory belongs to the system MS has always said not to modify it. Imagine if app A and app B want to use different versions of the same named DLL. Then what. Copying to the app directory is not a burden. It allows you simple installation, isolation, self-determination.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You make good points (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper solution is to place the driver file (eg., `libmysql.dll`) in your application's folder, or to place the installation location in your `FDDrivers.ini` file:

```
[MySQL]
Vendor=<folder>\libmysql.dll
```

(Recent versions of the documentation seem to use *VendorLib* instead of *Vendor* in the INI file.)

See the RAD Studio documentation topics [Configuring Drivers (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Configuring_Drivers_%28FireDAC%29) and [Connect to MySQL Server (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_%28FireDAC%29) for more information.

Comment: It's rather depressing that the official documentation to which you link blesses the system directory as a sound location for these files.

Comment: @David: Windows searches the system directory by default, and a lot of legacy software still installs there. If the vendor chose to do so, it's logical that you would look in the system's default search locations as well as your own. The docs don't *bless* anything - they just explain where the OS will look and in what order by default as well as where the FireDAC code looks.

Comment: @David: I stand corrected. A re-read of the docs does indeed say *You can take them...and place them*. You're absolutely right - the docs are wrong.

Comment: @Ken, I would say that it's as *unsafe* as setting up the `[MySQL]` section for your application's DBMS driver in global `FDDrivers.ini` file. Imagine what happens if everyone comes up with their own version and path to the library and decide to put it into the same named section.

Comment: @TLama: I didn't say anything about the *global* FDDrivers.ini file; in fact, I said *your FDDrivers.ini file*, and pointed to the documentation about where the drivers will look for the file. Whether it goes in the global driver configuration file depends, of course, on your particular circumstances; it would be safe in those for my applications (if we used FireDAC) because we're in a controlled environment where we control all applications that can be installed and none of the users are local admins. (It's a work network with very strict networking restrictions and group policies in place.)

Answer (score 2):

Let me to answer in two point.

1. Developing, live database connection!
   Hope you have on your data module an "TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink" component.
   Click this component and browse your LibMySQL.DLL into VendorLib. Should be work. But only in design time.
2. Runtime. Hopefully your DM created firstly in your project.
   In the DM's OnCreate event, you have to disconnect your library (I always ran my project with no database connection) and replace your "TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink"'s Vendorlib to LibMySQL.DLL (which is copied your  which is copied where the generated .EXE resided)

---

Have a nice day!