# Delphi application cannot see local MySQL dll

Tags: mysql, delphi, windows-10, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

We are seeing an issue with Delphi/FireDAC applications not seeing the required `libmysql.dll` despite the dll being in the same folder as the Executable.

The issue is only being seen on a single user who has had their machine reimaged. It is happening for all Delphi/FireDAC executables.

Our software is distributed with each Executable in it's own folder with a `libmysql.dll` and `FDConnections.ini` defining the required database connections for each application.

We don't distrbute FDDrivers.ini to users as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102373/firedac-error-314-but-dlls-are-in-program-directory), however on the user in question adding an `FDDrivers.ini` with a `VendorLib` set to the explicit location of the driver dll the error message changes but still cannot see the required file.

It feels as if the System (Windows 10) or possibly the AntiVirus are "hiding" the dll from the Application.

Has anyone seen similar?

Comment: Did you accidenticaly mix the bitness of the app and the dll, one being 32 bit and the other 64 bit?

Comment: The apps haven't changed. Most are on Network shares and are working for other people in the organisation. The issue is the one user who has had a machine rebuild.

Comment: Can you check with Dependency Walker where the app wants to load the DLL from?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Although as I mention adding an explicit FDDrivers.ini on the machine in question looks to be looking in the right place.

Comment: Could also run FireDAC Administrator ([FDAdministrator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/FDAdministrator)) on the machine and try and define a MySQL connection and then check the info tab to see if there are issues.