# unable to create connection to mysql from C++Builder

Tags: mysql, c++builder

I have C++Builder Community Edition. I am trying to create a connection from a blank project to `mysql` server. When I do a test, after supplying the right username and password, I get this error message:

```
Error: [FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libmysql.dll, libmariadb or libmysqld.dll]. The specified module could not be found
```

I was under the impression that one of the selling points of C++Builder is how easy to create a Windows form for database programming?

Comment: any code? What you use to connect with MySQL server (component? DLL? static or dynamic?)? do you have priviledges/access rights for accessing MySQL? Do you have `libmysql.dll` with correct version in search path or near executable? Is you MySQL server running and configured properly? Which C++ Builder version and VCL or FMX ? If all fails you can link and use libmysql on your own...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FireDac error 314 - but DLLs are in program directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102373/firedac-error-314-but-dlls-are-in-program-directory)

Answer (score 1):

It is Relatively easy! However you do need to read the docs and understand how FireDac works with C++ Builder/Delphi. One big consideration is the correct bitness of your executable, x86/x64, and which client libs you have on your machine?

If it is x86 then you can use the FireDAC Explorer from within the IDE to get connected, if you have set up the connection definitions correctly and, as Spektre wrote, have MySQL running ***locally***, it will connect?  The community version only supports local connections.

Specifically you need to ensure that the MySQL connection definition or string contains all the needed entries. If you're using Windows look in the file located at `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDConnectionDefs.ini` and make sure it is setup with the proper information.

Read the docs to see how FireDAC uses connection definition files and/or strings.  It does take a little effort to get it all working together so you have to be willing to learn it!  If after doing some of this, post again with what you've found and be specific and you may find people be willing to help you more.

[Embarcadero FireDAC Docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Working_with_Connections_(FireDAC))